# Translate Tick Marks

Tags: plotting, labeling, ticks

The code below creates a StreamPlot for a nonlinear system of first-order ODEs:

$\dot{x}=y,\dot{y}=x+\tfrac{1}{4}x^{2}$

I have created a simple zoom slider that expands the region about the critical point at $(x,y)=(0,0)$. In order to zoom about the other critical point at $(x,y)=(−4,0)$, I have written the system with a translation of $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(0,0)$. Unfortunately the location of the `Ticks` do not shift accordingly. In particular, by translating the point $(x,y)=(−4,0)$ to $(x,y)=(0,0)$, I want the $x$ `Tick` to be -4 instead of 0 and center the `StreamPlot` at $(x_0,y_0)$.  Can the `Ticks` be translated accordingly? Translating the $u$ and $v$ intervals by $x_0$ and $y_0$ respectively doesn't do it.

```
Manipulate[
 StreamPlot[{v + y0, (u + x0) + 1/4 (u + x0)^2}, {u, -r, r}, {v, -r, 
   r},
  StreamScale -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  FrameLabel -> {x, y},
  RotateLabel -> False,
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14],
  StreamPoints -> Fine,
  Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[0.01],Point[{{-x0, -y0}, {-4 - x0, -y0}}]}}],

  {{x0, 0, "x center"}, -6, 6, .01},
  {{y0, 0, "y center"}, -6, 6, .01},
  {{r, 6, "zoom"}, 6, 0.01, .01},
  Button["Reset", {x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 6}]
 ]
```

Comment: Move 'x0' from '(u+x0)' to the plot range '{x,-r+x0,r+x0}' in your 'StreamPlot'. Also, you can't define your points in terms of 'x0', 'y0' since those two values just represent a shift of the axes, so your points should be at '{0,0}', and '{-4,0}'

Comment: That did it! I thought that I had tried your fix, but obviously I must have coded it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the variable ranges, rather than translate the function; The points you are interested in are at a fixed position in the original frame, so don't move then either:

```
Manipulate[
 StreamPlot[
  {v, (u) + 1/4 (u)^2},
  {u, -r + x0, r + x0},
  {v, -r + y0, r + y0},
  StreamScale -> Automatic,
  AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500,
  FrameLabel -> {x, y}, RotateLabel -> False,
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 14],
  StreamPoints -> Fine, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[{{0, 0}, {-4, 0}}]}
 ],
 {{x0, 0, "x center"}, -6, 6, .01},
 {{y0, 0, "y center"}, -6, 6, .01},
 {{r, 6, "zoom"}, 6, 0.01, .01},
 Button["Reset", {x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r = 6}]
]
```